# Selenium XPath: Find element with text OR other text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, text

I am trying to figure out a way to locate an element with XPath based on two text strings. The element in question can have text A or text B, both of which are valid, and I need to assert that this element is visible, based upon this text. So I need an XPath expression like "//*...[contains(text(), 'A')] OR [contains(text(), 'B')]". Is this possible? This must be using XPath 1.0 as it is for Selenium Webdriver.

I have not found any way to do this, so I'm currently checking for the first string in a try-catch, then asserting for the second string afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, You can use XPath with **OR** Logical condition as follows :

- //*[contains(text(),'A') or contains(text(),'B')]
- //*[text()='exact_Text_1' or text()='exact_text_2']
- //*[@class='abc' or @class='pqr']

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, really helpful.